# How to make `QLineEdit` to blink

Tags: qt

I have got a setting' dialog in my application. There are `QLineEdit` in the dialog to set parameter. That parameter should be a number. When user type text in `QLineEdit` and press `Enter` or press to another widget I read text from `QLineEdit` and if text is not a number I put previous number in `QLineEdit`. Now I want `QLineEdit` to blink (like modal dialog blink when user press another component) for 3 seconds if user type wrong text in `QLineEdit`. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing to do is to create a custom widget that inherit from QLineEdit

But, an another quick way to achieve what you want to do is to connect the editing to a slot that makes a QTimer start. Then connect the timeout() signal to a slot that change the QLineEdit stylesheet.
No need to implement a separate QThread for this.

Comment: Yes, it is not simple to do it with another thread, it gives an error: `Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread`. I guess it is necessary to use `signals and slots` mechanism. As you said I inherited from `QLineWidget`and in `focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *ev)` function, in the case when typed value is not double I wrote:`for(int i=1;i<15;i+=2){
        QTimer::singleShot(100*i, this, SLOT(changeBackgroundColor()));
        QTimer::singleShot(100*(i+1), this, SLOT(retrieveBackgroundColor()));

    }` that works great for me!

Answer (score 0):

This is king of complicated, you have to overload the `paint()` function. You can forbid text input using a `Regexp` :

```
#include <QRegExpValidator>
[...]
QLineEdit editor;
QRegExp rx("([0-9])");
editor.setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(rx, this));
```

Comment: in that case it will be not possible to put double values

Comment: @lnk you just have to edit the regex to fit with double values and voilà

Comment: Yes, it is one of the solution. But isn't it possible to make `QLineEdit` to blink without overloading `paint()` function? I can change background color of `QLineEdit` with calling function setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{background: grey;}") then after 0.2 sec I should change color to white then again grey and so on for 3 seconds. But I should do it in new thread. Is it possible to do it in that way?

Comment: @lnk, to answer your question you need to try at least once and see whether it works. It will be faster than waiting fon an answer.

Comment: @lnk yes, you can, but this is tricky and non trivial, that's why I bring you this solution... Now if you want to use some timers you can, you seems to know a few about it but do you want some help ?

Comment: To elaborate on this answer, one can use the horrendous `^([+-]?)(?=\\d|\\.\\d)\\d*(\\.\\d*)?([Ee]([+-]?\\d+))?$` RegEx for a double precision number. A much cleaner alternative is to use `QDoubleValidator`. None of these blink, though.